# Циклический занос данных в базу данных

Tags: mysql, php, база-данных, сервер

Как циклическии занести в базу данных только 10 объектов, и потом ещё 10 объектов и т.д. пока они не кончаться

Проблема в том, что скрипт подаёт запрос на определённые файлы, откуда берёт данные, потом обрабатывает эти данные и заносит в бд, но этих файлов 100 и в каждый нужно подать запрос и обработать потом данные и ещё в бд подать запрос, при запуске такого скрипта выводит в итоге в браузере **Данные не получены** и возможно ли этот скрипт чтобы запускался на сервер сам в определённое время

Comment: @innot, ваш вопрос довольно непрозрачен и сложен для понимания. Пожалуйста, проведите разбор задачи (по пунктам) и перепишите в таком виде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> запускался на сервер сам в
> определённое время

- [cron](http://www.rhd.ru/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-AS-2.1-Manual/custom-guide/cron-task.html)
  Заводите файл/запись в бд - прогресс по файлам, т.е. все те файлы, которые осталось обработать.
  ПРи обработке файла, в случае успеха, вычеркиваете его.
  При старте скрипта

  select * from files limit 10

забрать 10 файлов.
После обрабатываете их и заносите в бд.

Comment: файлы идут не с моего сервера я парсю json файл